# Deserializing JSON in order to get a couple of parameters

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I'm having trouble understanding the JSON response I get. 
Here is the JSON(it's kinda big, and I apologize in advance for my c/p all of it) and I only need 3 attributes: name, price and category. I would preffer the ones I get in the bottom of the string, but I'm not sure if it's easier to get the nested ones..so actually, what's simpler, that would be my priority :)

```
{
"results":
[{
"sitedetails":[{
            "latestoffers":[{
                                "id":"6JotT9dMmWeYoi0UqKESoO",
                                "price":"1167.74",
                                "firstrecorded_at":1349396400,
                                "lastrecorded_at":1399787300,
                                "seller":"Walmart",
                                "availability":"Out of Stock",
                                "currency":"USD"
                            }],
                                "offers_count":1,
                                "name":"walmart.com",
                                "recentoffers_count":1,
                                "sku":"20604679",
                                "url":"http://www.walmart.com/ip/20604679"
            },
                {   
             "latestoffers":[{
                                "id":"5QTxsmf7GwYQWca60UQyAy",
                                "price":"1134.99",
                                "firstrecorded_at":1350835696,
                                "lastrecorded_at":1382836600,
                                "seller":"Newegg",
                                "availability":"OUT OF STOCK. [BBX: Buy Box]",
                                "currency":"USD"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"3l8ZNONJHyWoMsaO8AGoCQ",
                                "shipping":"14.30",
                                "price":"1134.99",
                                "firstrecorded_at":1360613800,
                                "lastrecorded_at":1362344900,
                                "seller":"newegg.com",
                                "availability":"Deactivated. This item is currently out of stock and it may or may not be restocked. [BBX: Buy Box]",
                                "currency":"USD"
                            }
                            ],
                    "offers_count":2,
                    "name":"newegg.com",
                    "recentoffers_count":1,
                    "sku":"N82E16834214948",
                    "url":"http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834214948"
                },
                {
            "latestoffers":[{
                                "id":"13XfN5eSpiAOyWmiKs6Kcs",
                                "price":"1026.00",
                                "firstrecorded_at":1379730300,
                                "lastrecorded_at":1379730300,
                                "seller":"Cheapgoodsz.com",
                                "availability":"Available",
                                "currency":"USD"
                            }],
                    "offers_count":1,
                    "name":"cheapgoodsz.com",
                    "recentoffers_count":1,
                    "sku":"8409",
                    "url":"http://www.cheapgoodsz.com/toshiba-toshiba-z830s8301-laptop-p-8409.html"
                }
            ],
"model":"PT225U 004004;Z830 S8301",
"weight":"1120373.15",
"price_currency":"USD",
"gtins":["00883974958450"],
"mpn":"PT225U-00400EN",
"sem3_help":"To view image links and additional merchants for this product, please upgrade your plan.",
"cat_id":"23130",
"height":"15.24",
"name":"Toshiba Portege Z830-S8301 13.3-Inch Netbook Computer",
"features":
            {
            "LCD Backlight Technology":"LED backlight",
            "64-bit Computing":"Yes",
            "Interfaces":"VGA LAN Microphone input Headphone output 2 x USB 2.0 USB 3.0 HDMI",
            "Run Time":"Up to 8.3 hour(s)",
            "CPU":"Intel Core i5 (2nd Gen) 2557M / 1.7 GHz",
            "Output":"45 Watt , 19 V , 2.37 A",
            "Ethernet Controller":"Intel 82579LM",
            "EPEAT Compliant":"EPEAT Gold",
            "Memory Card Reader":"Yes ( SD Card, miniSD, SDHC Memory Card, microSD )",
            "Chipset":"Mobile Intel QM67 Express",
            "Slots Qty":"1",
            "Microsoft Office Preloaded":"Includes a pre-loaded image of select Microsoft Office 2010 suites. Purchase an Office 2010 Product Key Card or disc to activate preloaded software on this PC.","Other Features":"Security lock slot (cable lock sold separately), Toshiba EasyGuard, Intel Active Management Technology (iAMT), USB Sleep-and-charge ports",
            "Wireless":"802.11n, Bluetooth 3.0 HS",
            "Sound":"Stereo speakers , microphone",
            "ENERGY STAR Qualified":"Yes",
            "Network Interface":"Gigabit Ethernet",
            "Input":"AC 120/230 V ( 50/60 Hz )",
            "System Type":"Ultrabook",
            "Image Aspect Ratio":"16:9",
            "Operating System":"Microsoft Windows 7 Professional (32/64 bits)",
            "Resolution":"1.3 Megapixel",
            "RAM":"4 GB ( 1 x 2 GB + 2 GB (soldered) )",
            "Camera":"Integrated webcam",
            "Max Operating Temperature":"95 Ã\u201aÂ°F",
            "Max Allocated RAM Size":"1696 MB",
            "Cache":"L3 - 3 MB",
            "Localization":"United States",
            "Humidity Range Operating":"20 - 80% (non-condensing)",
            "Service & Support Details":"Limited warranty - 3 years Limited warranty - battery - 1 year",
            "Compliant Standards":"RoHS",
            "Number of Cores":"Dual-Core",
            "Graphics Processor":"Intel HD Graphics 3000",
            "Interface":"Serial ATA-300",
            "Wireless Controller":"Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230",
            "Security":"Trusted Platform Module (TPM 1.2) Security Chip , fingerprint reader",
            "Speed":"1333 MHz",
            "Memory Allocation Technology":"Dynamic Video Memory Technology",
            "Min Operating Temperature":"41 Ã\u201aÂ°F",
            "Service & Support":"3 years warranty",
            "Audio Features":"MaxxAudio 3",
            "Max RAM Supported":"6 GB",
            "Capacity":"47 Wh",
            "Hard Drive":"128 GB SSD",
            "Software Included":"Adobe Acrobat Reader, Google Toolbar, Adobe Flash Player, Skype, Toshiba Assist, Toshiba Recovery DiskCreator, Windows Live Essentials, Toshiba PC Health Monitor, Toshiba Eco Utility, Toshiba ReelTime, Toshiba Bulletin Board, Google Chrome, Toshiba Media Controller, Microsoft Silverlight, Toshiba Disc Creator, Toshiba Fingerprint Utility, Toshiba Security Assist, Toshiba Value Added Package, Windows Live Messenger, Face Recognition software, Windows Live Photo Gallery, Windows Live Mail, Windows Live Writer, Microsoft Windows Media Player 12, Toshiba Service Station, Toshiba Hardware Setup Utility, Toshiba Web Camera Application, Toshiba Online Backup (30 days trial), Windows Live Movie Maker, Microsoft Office 2010 Starter, Toshiba App Place, Toshiba Book Place, Toshiba HDD/SSD Alert, Toshiba Sleep Utility, Toshiba Password Utility, Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0, Toshiba Device Access Control, Toshiba Resolution+, Norton Internet Security 2012 (30 days trial), Intel Wireless Display Technology 2.1",
            "Max Turbo Speed":"2.7 GHz",
            "Technology":"8-cell lithium ion",
            "Widescreen":"Yes"
            },
"length":"227.08",
"created_at":1347480704,
"geo":["usa"],
"width":"315.98",
"upc":"883974958450",
"ean":"0883974958450",
"category":"Netbooks",
"price":"1026.00",
"updated_at":1399832844,
"color":"Silver",
"manufacturer":"Toshiba America Information Systems",
"images_total":0,
"brand":"Toshiba",
"sem3_id":"2iTwoIQGhEKMiW62moMy0u",
"offers_total":74
}]
,"total_results_count":1,
"results_count":1,
"code":"OK",
"offset":0
}
```

I think I'm doing something completely wrong here. I searched for some answers that could help me and in the end I made my own deserializer:

```
public class ProductInfo {


String name;

String category;
Double price;

public ProductInfo(){}
public ProductInfo(String name, String category, Double price){
    this.name=name;
    this.category=category;
    this.price=price;
}

public ProductInfo deserialize(JSONObject results, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {



    return new ProductInfo(
            results.getString("name").toString(),
            results.getString("category").toString(),
            results.getDouble("price"));

        // USED THIS WHILE I WAS USING GSON 
        //  jobject.get("name").getAsString(),
        //  jobject.get("category").getAsString(), 
        //  jobject.get("price").getAsDouble());
}
```

Here is how I use this deserializer in my main:

```
JSONObject results = products.getProducts();     //I get the JSONObject from a link here.
ProductInfo pi = new ProductInfo();
pi.deserialize(results, type, context );
```

If someone could explain how exactly do I get to the parameters I need, that would be awesome. Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: And here is the exception I get:
`Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["name"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:472)
 at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:653)
 at proba.ProductInfo.deserialize(ProductInfo.java:31)
 at proba.Main.main(Main.java:51)`

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: Hint: Reformat your JSON so that `[` and `{` (and `]` and `}`) are on different lines and properly indented.  This will make it easier to see the structure.

Comment: And with most JSON kits, if you simply do println of the toString of the JSON entity it will print in a nicely formatted form.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's because "results" is an array and is inside another object, and "name" is inside "result". So you need to do something like this.

```
JSONObject response = products.getProducts();
JSONObject result = response.getJSONArray("results").get(0);
ProductInfo pi = new ProductInfo();
pi.deserialize(result, type, context );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the JSON syntax and realized I have a JSONArray with only 1 JSONObject that consists of several other JSONArrays(which further on consist of other JSONObjects etc.).
I only need that first JSONObject with index 0 in the mentioned JSONArray. So here is my new deserializer:

```
public ProductInfo deserialize(JSONObject results, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

JSONArray resultsArray = results.getJSONArray("results");

JSONObject objekt = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
String name = objekt.get("name").toString();
String category = objekt.get("category").toString();
String price =  objekt.get("price").toString();


return new ProductInfo(name, category,  price);
}
```

When I try to get the name/value pair, it only gives me `nullnullnull` when I try to print it like this in my main:

`System.out.println(pi.getName()+pi.getCategory()+pi.getPrice());`

Any1 knows why are the values `null` ?